# How to improve nested for loops over DataFrame going through all possible column combinations in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and I'm using nested for loops to go through all available combinations of certain columns. I created an exemplifying code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import unique

df = DataFrame([[30, 'DEV1', 'X4Y4', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [30, 'DEV1', 'X5Y5', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [30, 'DEV2', 'X4Y4', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [30, 'DEV2', 'X5Y5', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [85, 'DEV1', 'X4Y4', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [85, 'DEV1', 'X5Y5', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [85, 'DEV2', 'X4Y5', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]],
                [85, 'DEV2', 'X5Y5', [0, 1, 2, 3], [1E-5, 2E-5, 3E-5, 4E-5]]],
               columns=['Temperature', 'Device', 'Coordinate', 'Voltage', 'Current'])

Temperature = unique(df['Temperature'])
for temperature in Temperature:
    df1 = df.query("Temperature == @temperature")
    Device = unique(df1['Device'])
    for device in Device:
        df2 = df1.query("Device == @device")
        Coordinate = unique(df2['Coordinate'])
        for coordinate in Coordinate:
            df3 = df2.query("Coordinate == @coordinate")
            # do something with df3['Voltage'] and df3['Current']
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Online I was reading about using `groupby` and `agg` but I didn't quite get how to apply it to my case.

Could you please share your ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the for loop? Is there a desired output frame that you can show?

Comment: @SomeDude I use the data to do various things, be it extracting a df3['Current'] at a certain df3['Voltage'] and appending it to a list, or plot(df3['Voltage'], df3['Current']), or first do a linear regression and then plot the fitting and append the fit parameters to a list, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first apply groupy function and then use groups property of it. It will return the dict having the key values all possible combinations of columns values and values of dict are labels.

```
list(df.groupby(["Temperature","Device","Coordinate"]).groups.keys())


[(30, 'DEV1', 'X4Y4'),
 (30, 'DEV1', 'X5Y5'),
 (30, 'DEV2', 'X4Y4'),
 (30, 'DEV2', 'X5Y5'),
 (85, 'DEV1', 'X4Y4'),
 (85, 'DEV1', 'X5Y5'),
 (85, 'DEV2', 'X4Y5'),
 (85, 'DEV2', 'X5Y5')]
```